# Is there a way to export or import individual display views?

Tags: 7, views, importing-exporting

I am looking for a way to import and export individual Views displays and found this issue on drupal.org, [Export/Import individual display views [#1470318]](https://www.drupal.org/project/views/issues/1470318).

Has such a functionality available been developed, even through a module?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of.

An option. If they’re so similar that you can just do export and reimport to another view, you could keep them on the same view, clone the display, rename the display, override whatever field/filter you need to change and change it.